# Why BiometricPrompt API in Xamarin Android doesn't contain onAuthenticationError Callback

Tags: xamarin.android

In Android Studios BiometricPrompt API contains a callback named onAuthenticationError which gets triggered when the user touch outside the BiometricPrompt dialog and once a user tries to input an invalid Biometric to the device. But the BiometricPrompt API available in Xamarin.Android platform doesn't provide onAuthenticationError callback.

I created an android application using Android Studios to check BiometricPrompt API there I could access the callback named onAuthenticationError. Then I deployed the application to a device and debugged the application. The above mentioned callback got triggered when I touched any area outside the  BiometricPrompt dialog and it also got triggered every time I provided BiometricPrompt with a invalid input more than 5 times.
Then I tried developing the same application in Xamain.Android and there I was unable to find any callback named onAuthenticationError. When I deployed and tested the application in a device as the above-mentioned callback was not available I couldn't handle the 2 scenarios 
where when the user touches any area outside the  BiometricPrompt dialog and when user provides the BiometricPrompt with an invalid input more than 5 times.

My Native android code snippet.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback getAuthenticationCallback() {

return new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    @Override
  **  public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                      CharSequence errString) {
        notifyUser("Authentication error: " + errString);
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
    }**

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode,
                                     CharSequence helpString) {
        super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
            BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
        notifyUser("Authentication Succeeded");
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
    }
};
```

}

My Xamarin.Android code snippet

```
public class BiometricAuthCallBacks : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback
{
public TaskCompletionSource<LocalAuthStatus> promise = new TaskCompletionSource<LocalAuthStatus>();

private int failCount;

public override void OnAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result)
{
    base.OnAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
    promise.TrySetResult(LocalAuthStatus.Success);
    //Success(result);
}

public override void OnAuthenticationFailed()
{
    base.OnAuthenticationFailed();
    failCount++;
    if (failCount>=5)
    {
        promise.TrySetResult(LocalAuthStatus.Fail);
    }
    //Failed();
}

public override void OnAuthenticationHelp([GeneratedEnum] BiometricAcquiredStatus helpCode, ICharSequence helpString)
{
    base.OnAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
    promise.TrySetResult(LocalAuthStatus.Error);
    //Help(helpCode, helpString);
}
```

}

My Question is why can't I access onAuthenticationError callback from Xamarin.Android platform and how can I resolve this?

Comment: For some weird reason I do not have direct access to these API's in my VS can you suggest what version of VS17 do you have?

Comment: @G.hakim I am using Visual Studio for Mac Version 7.8.3 (build 2) and also make sure that you have set the target SDK version to API 28 (Pie).